Add a page directly under the workspace using Notion API
I'm currently trying to implement adding pages using Notion's API.
I have confirmed that a new page can be added by specifying the ID of the page or database (table), but is it not possible to add a page to the workspace?
I thought it would work if I passed it in the form below, but an error is returned...
{
  "parent": {
    "type": "workspace",
    "workspace": true
  }
}

"message": "body failed validation. Fix one:\nbody.parent.page_id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.parent.database_id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.",

Can someone please help me?
